# Build error when having an "adapters" folder in "common"

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst

Building a MobileFirst project that has an "adapters" folder in the "common" environment, causes a build error: "Adapter deployment failed: Adapter 'xxx' contains errors ". I guess the build system is looking for an "adapters" folder anywhere (and should only look in the root).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for the report. The development team will investigate. There is obviously no workaround... Other than using a different name for the folder.

If you'll want a fix for this issue you'll need to one a PMR support ticket.

Comment: Tried MFPF 7.0 and this still happens for folders named 'services'

Comment: Did you open a PMR to receive a fix? "mfpf 7.0" does not mean much. There are a lot of builds of MFPF 7.0...